# How can I use FireStorage in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, uikit, firebase-storage

my project is about uploading and saving images to database, then do ML algorithms.
I want to upload any selected data to my firebase. I linked it to my project and be below code is what i did.
But no images uploaded to my firebase storage.
What could be the problem?

```
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = image
            
            // Set the selected image to the image view
            imageView.image = selectedImage
            
            }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    
    @IBAction func didTapUpload() {
        uploadImage()
    }
    
    func uploadImage(){
        //make sure the user selected in image
        guard selectedImage != nil else {
            return
        }
        // Create storage refrence
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        // Turn images to data
        let jpegData = selectedImage!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
        
        guard jpegData != nil else {
            return
        }
    
        // file path and name
        let fileRef = storageRef.child("Images/\(UUID().uuidString).jpeg")

        // Upload data
        _ = fileRef.putData(jpegData!, metadata: nil){
            metadata, error in
            
            //check for errors
            if error == nil && metadata != nil{
                
            }
        }
        // LATER: save refrences to Filestore database
        
    }
    
    
    // Function for canceling the image picker.
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And how can i use the UIImage anywhere in the code? i put imageView.image

Comment: Your child path is Images/\(UUID().uuidString).jpeg?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance,  so it's hard to say what's going wrong. I recommend debugging this locally and telling us the result. So if you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: There are a number of places where the code could be failing - but because errors are not being handled, it will silently fail and you're never know why. Along with troubleshooting as @frankvanpuffelen suggested, please add code to handle potential errors by providing meaningful output when they occur. For example here `guard selectedImage != nil else {` - instead of returning, add `print("the user didn't select an image")` and then `return`. That will go a long way to tracking down troublesome issues.